# Macbook air wifi problem when is on my legs

Tags: wifi, macbook-pro

I've a strange problem with my macbook air. When I use it on my legs, wifi doesn't work or disconnects. I need to raise up the mac in order to get the signal. I'm in a small flat and the signal is very strong. 
Anyone has got a similar issue?

thanks

UPDATE 1

It seems the position won't cause the problem, but using a ping command through automator will help to not disconnect.

Answer (score -1):

I have solved removing all ssid stored and then creating a new location in network preferences. However the issue seems to be caused by the energy saver system. In fact, using automator pinging the router ip address every 0.2 sec works too.

Comment: We like answers to include the relevant details, not just a link, in them. This prevents link rot from happening, where a page on a site goes away after time.